How to stop multiple threads when one thread meets a specific condition
I am working on this program which finds a solution to 8 queen puzzle.
The user is prompted to enter the value of n which is the chess board dimension. The runSearch() method of HillClimbingSearch is then called to compute a solution and the board solution is printed if/when it is found.
To make the program more efficient, I am using 100 threads that run concurrently and execute runSearch() method. However, the program is printing out 100 solutions from the 100 threads.
I need it to print only one first solution from the corresponding thread. Just need to modify Main class/runSearch() method but I am stuck.
Here is my code:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0;
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Enter the number of Queens :");
                n = s.nextInt();
                if (n == 2 || n == 3) {
                    System.out.println("No Solution possible for " + n + " Queens. Please enter another number");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        long timestamp1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Solution to " + n + " queens using hill climbing search:");

        // Create 100 threads for hill climbing search
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("HillClimbingGroup");

        // Create 100 threads for hill climbing search
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            HillClimbingSearch h = new HillClimbingSearch(n);
            Thread t = new Thread(threadGroup, h);
            t.start();
            h.runSearch();
        }

        // Wait for all threads to finish
        while (threadGroup.activeCount() > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Printing the solution
        long timestamp2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeDiff = timestamp2 - timestamp1;
        System.out.println("Execution Time: " + timeDiff + " ms");
    }
}

And…
//Program to implement Hill Climbing with random restart to solve N-queens problem
import java.util.Random;


    public class HillClimbingSearch extends Thread {
        private int n ;
        private int heuristic = 0;
        private int presentHeuristic;
        private NQueen[] finalSolution;
    
        public  HillClimbingSearch (int size) {
            n = size;
            finalSolution = null;
        }
    
        public NQueen[] getFinalSolution() {
            return finalSolution;
        }
    
        //Method to create a new random board
        public NQueen[] generateBoard() {
            NQueen[] startBoard = new NQueen[n];
            Random rndm = new Random();
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                startBoard[i] = new NQueen(rndm.nextInt(n), i);
            }
            return startBoard;
        }
    
        //Method to print the Current State
        public  void printState (NQueen[] state) {
            //Creating temporary board from the present board
            int[][] tempBoard = new int[n][n];
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                //Get the positions of Queen from the Present board and set those positions as 1 in temp board
                tempBoard[state[i].getRow()][state[i].getColumn()]=1;
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                for (int j= 0; j < n; j++) {
                    System.out.print(tempBoard[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    
        // Method to find Heuristics of a state
        public  int findHeuristic (NQueen[] state) {
            int heuristic = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i< state.length; i++) {
                for (int j=i+1; j<state.length; j++ ) {
                    if (state[i].ifConflict(state[j])) {
                        heuristic++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return heuristic;
        }
    
        // Method to get the next board with lower heuristic
        public NQueen[] nextBoard (NQueen[] presentBoard) {
            NQueen[] nextBoard = new NQueen[n];
            NQueen[] tmpBoard = new NQueen[n];
            int presentHeuristic = findHeuristic(presentBoard);
            int bestHeuristic = presentHeuristic;
            int tempH;
    
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                //  Copy present board as best board and temp board
                nextBoard[i] = new NQueen(presentBoard[i].getRow(), presentBoard[i].getColumn());
                tmpBoard[i] = nextBoard[i];
            }
            //  Iterate each column
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                if (i>0)
                    tmpBoard[i-1] = new NQueen (presentBoard[i-1].getRow(), presentBoard[i-1].getColumn());
                tmpBoard[i] = new NQueen (0, tmpBoard[i].getColumn());
                //  Iterate each row
                for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                    //Get the heuristic
                    tempH = findHeuristic(tmpBoard);
                    //Check if temp board better than best board
                    if (tempH < bestHeuristic) {
                        bestHeuristic = tempH;
                        //  Copy the temp board as best board
                        for (int k=0; k<n; k++) {
                            nextBoard[k] = new NQueen(tmpBoard[k].getRow(), tmpBoard[k].getColumn());
                        }
                    }
                    //Move the queen
                    if (tmpBoard[i].getRow()!=n-1)
                        tmpBoard[i].move();
                }
            }
            //Check whether the present bord and the best board found have same heuristic
            //Then randomly generate new board and assign it to best board
            if (bestHeuristic == presentHeuristic) {
                nextBoard = generateBoard();
                heuristic = findHeuristic(nextBoard);
            } else
                heuristic = bestHeuristic;
            return nextBoard;
        }
    
       public void runSearch() {
            NQueen[] presentBoard = generateBoard();
            presentHeuristic = findHeuristic(presentBoard);
            // test if the present board is the solution board
            while (presentHeuristic != 0 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                presentBoard = nextBoard(presentBoard);
                presentHeuristic = findHeuristic(presentBoard);
            }
            if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                finalSolution = presentBoard;
                printState(finalSolution);
            }
        }
    
    
    }

And…
//Class for N-queens Problem
public class NQueen {
    private int row;
    private int column;

    public NQueen(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    public void move () {
        row++;
    }

    public boolean ifConflict(NQueen q){
        //  Check rows and columns
        if(row == q.getRow() || column == q.getColumn())
            return true;
            //  Check diagonals
        else if(Math.abs(column-q.getColumn()) == Math.abs(row-q.getRow()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }
}


The short answer is - you design for it.  This means that you each thread will need to monitor for some kind of "termination" state which you can set externally, which means you will need to maintain a reference to the running threads

You should review how to use Threads in Java. At present your HillClimbingSearch class extends Thread. It should implement Runnable. Why do you call h.runSearch() from your main thread?

Watch your code formatting when posting. Code must either be indented by four SPACE characters on all lines, or else wrapped in a pair of three back-ticks. I think I fixed your code formatting today, but verify.
